# GSub with a plus/minus character

Tags: lua

I am trying to convert a text source into an HTML readable page.

The code I have have tried:

```
local newstr=string.gsub(str,"±", "&plusmn;")
local newstr=string.gsub(str,"%±", "&plusmn;")
```

However, the character shows up as `Â` in the output.

I can't seem to find any other documentation on how to handle this specific special character. How do I handle this character when reading in so that it will output properly?

Edit: After trying suggestions I'm able to determine this:

```
local function sanitizeheader(str)
    if not(str)then return "" end
    str2 = "Depth ±"
    local newstr=string.gsub(str2, string.char(177), "&plusmn;")
    return newstr
end
```

In the testing, if I use str2 ± does show up in the output. However, when I try to use str as it is passed in from reading the excel file, it doesn't pick up the character and still returns the `Â` character.

Comment: This is a codepage issue.  What is your OS?  What is the encoding of your source code?

Comment: Try both variants: `string.gsub(str, string.char(194,177), "&plusmn;")` and `string.gsub(str, string.char(177), "&plusmn;")`.

Comment: To figure out the encoding of your Lua sourcecode, you can add this to your script and run it: `print(("±"):gsub(".", function (b) return ("\\x%02X"):format(string.byte(b)) end))`. That will print a representation of the bytes that are used to encode this character. If this prints two bytes, \xC2\xB1, your Lua script is in UTF-8 encoding; if one byte, \xB1, the encoding is probably ISO 8859-1 or Windows 1252. But there are other Lua-compatible encodings that contain this character.

Comment: The source is the header row of an Excel file (xlsx). When I run the script provided by cyclaminist it shows \xB1.

Comment: I am using the SciTE editor to run the scripts.

Comment: I've tried changing both the Excel and the Encoding settings in SciTE to UTF-8 with no success, still getting the A character. The original encoding of the Excel file was "Western European (Windows)"

Comment: Okay, so "Western European" is the name for Windows codepage 1252. I can't figure out why you'd be seeing the character Â on its own. You would see the characters Â± (mojibake) if a file encoded in UTF-8 were being viewed as Windows 1252. UTF-8 encodes the character ± as the bytes `"\xC2\xB1"`; those same bytes encode the characters Â± in Windows 1252 (Western European). But the file isn't in UTF-8, and nothing that you've posted here would cause the second byte to vanish, leaving `"\xB1"` (Â).

Comment: I downloaded SciTE and can't see a way to convert between encodings. The File -> Encoding menu just changes how the file is _displayed_. But you shouldn't need to change the encoding if both files are in the same encoding.

Comment: To verify the encoding of the Excel file, you can search for the plus-minus character and print its bytes. Copy text containing the character and replace the plus-minus with a byte pattern that captures one or two "characters" (bytes) outside of the ASCII range. So if the text is _Depth ±_: `plus_minus = string.match(text_source, "Depth ([\127-\255][\127-\255]?)")`. Then print the bytes with `print(plus_minus:gsub(".", function (b) return ("\\x%02X"):format(string.byte(b)) end))`. If this prints the same thing as the previous little script, the two files are probably in the same encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua string assume strings as sequence of bytes. You are trying utf8 multi byte character. The code you are trying should work as it just replacing a sequence of bytes. However, Lua 5.3 has utf8 library to handle unicode character

```
local str="±®ª"

for code in str:gmatch(utf8.charpattern) do
  print("&#" .. utf8.codepoint(code) .. ";")
end
```

Output:

```
&#177;
&#174;
&#170;
```

Check [Lua Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.5) for more info.